# General error: 1 Can't create/write to file errcode:2

Tags: php, mysql, linux, file-permissions, database-permissions

I am trying to write a CSV file to `/var/www/VistaMind_CMStmp` and I get the error Message: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/VistaMind_CMS/tmp/app_users.csv' (Errcode: 2)`

I tried doing `chown mysql:mysql` `/var/www/VistaMind_CMS/tmp`, but that does not work. I do not want to modify my TMPDIR var in my.cnf, which is currently set to /var/www, but instead, I want MySQL to dump a database table to /var/www/VistaMind_CMS/tmp.

Please help!

My code is :

```
    $file_path = $this->view->baseUrl()."/../tmp/app_users.csv";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users INTO OUTFILE '".$file_path."' ".
            "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
    $stmt = $db->query($sql, array());
    echo "Done!!";
```

Comment: please share your code...

Comment: Just edited my question to include the php code.

Comment: @Sonu Jha - Did DevZer0 answer your question below? If so, please mark it as the answer. Your comment on his answer is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `chown mysql:mysql /var/www/VistaMind_CMS/tmp`.

Comment: @SonuJha accept it as right answer so others can understand it works.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the chown did not fix the problem. I followed the second step in the following post which finally solved my problem

http://www.mydailyhacks.org/2014/11/08/how-can-i-backup-a-mysql-database-or-export-it-to-a-file/

(I had to change the tmpdir used by mysql)