# MySQL into outfile not working from PHP application but working in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos

I am trying to do an "INTO OUTFILE" query to output a csv file on a Linux CentOS machine using PHP application.

Here is the query:

```
(SELECT 'Date', 'Customer', 'Customer name', 'Commission', 'User', 'Value') UNION (SELECT t1.`DATE`, t1.`CUSTOMER`, t1.`CUSTOMERNAME`, t1.`COMMISSION`, t1.`USER`, t1.`VALUE` FROM `raws` t1, `roles` t2 ORDER BY `CUSTOMER`, `CUSTOMERNAME`, `COMMISSION`, `USER`, `DATE` ASC INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/myapp/downloads/524e6b306c451.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ')
```

Here are some details to the problem:

- mysql runs the query fine and outputs a .csv file at the correct directory `"/var/www/html/myapp/downloads"`
- The PHP app, however, returns an error that says `"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file"`
- both mysql and PHP are running using the same user, root
- The PHP app runs fine on Windows machine with XAMPP
- The PHP app runs if I exclude `"into outfile"` query.

Based on the above, I am convinced that it has something to do with file permission on my CentOS machine. However, even after I have done `chmod -R 777 /var/www`, I still get the same error.

Please help, and thanks in advance

EDIT:

`ls -la /var/www/html/myapp/downloads` looks like the following:

```
drwxrwsrwt. 2 mysql mysql  4096 Oct  4 10:37 .
drwxrwsrwx. 9 root  www    4096 Oct  4 07:56 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 55353 Oct  4 10:36 524e67124bba4.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 51195 Oct  4 10:04 524e7699a69a7.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 51195 Oct  4 10:07 524e7737c54ad.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql 51195 Oct  4 10:08 524e7782a21a3.csv
```

Comment: What does ls -al /var/www/html/myapp/downloads output look like?

Comment: @user1455836 hey added the output in the edit thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be permission error. MySQL may not able to access your /tmp directory to wirte and create temporary files. Make sure /tmp is owned by root and sticky bit is set on /tmp directory. Type the following commands to see if it fixes the error:

```
chown root:root /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

and restart mysql server

Answer (score 0):

[General error: 1 Can't create/write to file errcode:2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520611/general-error-1-cant-create-write-to-file-errcode2) This would sort it out with chown.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker